# Writing a file to a buffer

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy over one file to another as a sort of academic exercise. It "seems" to be working fine when I print the in and out files, but the `strlen` and comparisons using `strcmp` show that they are not identical. Here is what I have:

```
$ cat in.txt
Hello
There
It's me, ok?
```

```
void cat(const char* filepath, char buffer[], size_t len)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    if (!f) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    size_t cur = 0;

    for (int ch; (ch=getc(f)) != EOF && cur < len; cur++) {
        buffer[cur] = ch;
    }
    buffer[cur] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
}
```

```
int main(void)
 {
   FILE *in  = fopen("in.txt", "r");
   FILE *out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
   char buffer[40];
   while (fgets(buffer, 40, in)) {
       fputs(buffer, out);
   }
   fclose(in) && fclose(out);

   char in_contents[200], out_contents[200];
   cat("in.txt", in_contents, 200);
   cat("out.txt", out_contents, 200);
   printf("%s%sSame? %s\n", in_contents, out_contents, strcmp(in_contents, out_contents)==0?"Yes":"No");
}
```

> Hello 
> There 
> It's me, ok? 
> Hello 
> There 
> It's me, ok? 
> Same? No

What does it seem like I'm doing wrong in either copying over the contents or comparing it?

---

Hmm...it seems like this whole thing was fixed but putting an `fflush(out)` before the `fclose`. Does the `fclose` not automatically flush the buffer?

Comment: Inspect the contents of the `in_contents` and `out_contents` buffers in a debugger. Look at every character and verify whether they are indeed the same.

Comment: Code is writing the _null chracter_ maybe outside  the array with `buffer[cur] = '\0';`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it seems it was the same, the buffer just wasn't flushed when I did the comparison (see end of question). Also, the example is pretty contrived so it'd never be writing outside the array -- the text is ~40 chars only.

Comment: the problem is the **way to clever** `fclose(in) && fclose(out);`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what's wrong with that?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 "see end of answer" --> There is no posted answer yet

Comment: well why'd you write that? What does `fclose()` return, how does `&&` work...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see, yes putting that onto separate lines fixes the issue as well...want to post an answer with why that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the file because of `fclose(in) && fclose(out);`. Upon success `fclose(in)` will return 0, and it will make `&&` short-circuit and not run `fclose(out);`. To fix replace `&&` with `+`, `-`, `*` or `,`. You could also consider using a `;` instead.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. By the way, does doing `fclose(out)` automatically flush that output file?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 yes. that is guaranteed... unless `fclose` fails. But if it fails then you cannot do anything anyway.

Comment: thanks, anyways, I think just putting it on separate lines makes it more readable anyways (at least to me).

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 of course it does. Please promise you'll not use `&&` like that any more :D

Answer (score 2):

Operator && is using short circuit logic. Thus if the return value of fclose(in) is 0 what means a success then fclose(out) is **not** executed. Do not use &&

Comment: Do not use `||` either here. It's not that hard to put two `close()` on two different lines.